# set size for jsp:include tag

Tags: jsp, jstl, jspinclude

Is there any way to set size for a jsp:include tab?
I have the following code

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="fromDatabase">
   <jsp:include page="GenericDB.jsp" flush="true" />
</div>
```

The page contents are less. But still it is showing scroll bar in the page. I tried to set width in the DIV  tag.

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="fromDatabase" style="width:800px">
   <jsp:include page="GenericDB.jsp" flush="true" />
</div>
```

Then the size reduced but it was showing scroll bar inside the div area.
Is there anyway to size of jsp:include? Thanks

Comment: jsp:include just includes the result of the included JSP into the generated HTML. It doesn't have any size. It's not an HTML element, but an instruction generated at server-side. That's like asking if it's possible to set the size of servlet.doGet(). Doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I was just asking only is there any attribute for the tag.

Comment: So I cannot set size in any other way?

Comment: You can use CSS on HTML elements. jsp:include is not an HTML element. It's a server-side instruction. Something like a method call. Forget that the HTML page is generated using a JSP. Concentrate on the generated HTML, as if it was a static HTML page.

Comment: How can i set it if possible?

Comment: Do you actually read the comments? YOU CAN'T. IT MAKES NO SENSE.

Comment: Oh. sorry. I read that after I commenting that only.